# 痛いの慣れた！ How is particle の working here?

Tags: particle-の, nominalization

In response to me talking about how guitar hurts my fingers, a native speaker replied

> 痛いの慣れた！

Which I believe means "I'm used to the pain"

How can I generalize this grammar of "い adjective + の + verb (in ta form or other)"

I can't find this on Bunpro or my grammar book, so I'm lost to how it works.

Comment: Look up の as a nominalizer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That の is a nominalizer, and a particle is omitted after it.

> ［痛いの］｛は／に／には｝慣れた。

Comment: To add onto this slightly, you can think of 「痛いの」as meaning "the fact that it hurts".

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Can I generalize it to all い adjectives?  Like 怖いの "the fact that it's scary"?  So maybe 怖いの慣れた makes sense?  Like "The fact that it is scary, I'm used to it" or less robotically "I'm use to it being scary"?

Comment: Is there a difference between this construction, and instead saying 痛みに慣れた or 痛さに慣れた？

Comment: @Catdog Yes 怖いの慣れた, 暑いの慣れた, 臭いの慣れた and so on make sense, too.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer 痛いの慣れた is much more colloquial. It's rarely used in the narrative part of a novel.